# Entity Framework migration for ASP.Net Core Identity creates key without key length

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

Using ASP.NET Core Identity and Entity Framework Core 5.0 (EF Tools also 5.0.0), the migration code generated created key (for tables like `ApplicationUser`, from `IdentityUser`) with Id and no key length.

Getting an error when running with MySql:

> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): BLOB/TEXT column 'Id' used in key specification without a key length

For example:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity("MyProject.ApplicationUser", b =>
        {
            b.Property<string>("Id")
                .HasColumnType("TEXT");
        }
```

Comment: `.HasColumnType("TEXT")` does not look standard, what EF Core version is this? And do you have custom code in `OnModelCreating` like `.HasColumnType`?

Comment: Updated post to say .Net Core 5.0.0. OnModalCreating only has base.OnModelCreating and modelBuilder.ConfigurePersistedGrantContext(_operationalStoreOptions.Value);

Comment: There are four TEXT types:`TINYTEXT TEXT MEDIUMTEXT LONGTEXT`,I think you can use the type of `TINYTEXT`.

Comment: This item may be something to be raised as an issue with the ASP.Net team, as I think the Ids in the migration should work by default with major DBs like MySql.

Comment: @JonasArcangel Actually it might be MySql EF Core provider issue, because identity [does not configure](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/IdentityUserContext.cs#L126) string key max length. So the issue should reproduce with arbitrary entity having string PK. With the exact same setup SqlServer provider implicitly puts 450 length limit, so I guess MySql is supposed to do something like that based on underlying database restrictions. Also which MySql provider are you using? As I see, Pomelo still has no official 5.0 release, same for Oracle.

Comment: I thought that migration code should be provider agnostic. The problem was that my build-time provider is Sqlite. This is a problem. I want my software to cater to MySql, Sqlite, and MS SQL, but each one generates migrations differently.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was using Sqlite as provider during build time. It was generating migration appropriate for Sqlite, and not for MySQL.

Our solution, as we need to cater to Sqlite, MySQL and MS SQL, is to create a DBContext for each provider, and abstract it away to be used by the services.